# Will someone translate these characters into English?

Tags: character-identification, seal

[image]These are from an old scroll painting. I am trying to identify the artist.

Comment: Do you mind showing us the remaining of the scroll painting?

Answer (score 0):

The first one is 張 (zhāng), and about the second one, I'm not so sure, could be 直 zhí Probably?